# Boost function map to string

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, boost

I am trying to map a string to a function.  The function should get a `const char*` passed in.  I am wondering why I keep getting the error that

```
*no match for call to ‘(boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (*)(const char*), boost::_bi::list0>) (const char*)’*
```

My code is below

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>



typedef boost::function<void(const char*)> fun_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, fun_t> funs_t;



void $A(const char *msg)
{
    std::cout<<"hello $A";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   std::string p = "hello";
   funs_t f;
   f["$A"] = boost::bind($A);
   f["$A"](p.c_str());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd caution you against using non-standard identifiers like `$A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, using `boost::bind` is completely superfluous. You can just assign the function itself (it will converted to a pointer to a function, and be type erased by `boost::function` just fine).

Since you do bind, it's not enough to just pass the function. You need to give `boost::bind` the argument when binding, or **specify a placeholder** if you want to have the bound object forward something to your function. You can see it in the error message, that's what `boost::_bi::list0` is there for.

So to resolve it:

```
f["$A"] = boost::bind($A, _1);
```

Or the simpler

```
f["$A"] = $A;
```

---

Also, as I noted to you in the comment, I suggest you avoid identifiers which are not standard. A `$` isn't a valid token in an identifier according to the C++ standard. Some implementations *may* support it, but not all are required to.